# Logical Indexing with multiple replacements in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing, logical-operators

"Write a single instruction of Matlab that will take a vector x and change it to y such that any element of `x` that is greater than `1` is set to `y=1;` every element of `x` less than `-1` is set to `y=-1;` and for elements of `x` *between -1 and +1* we have `y=x`. Test it on k, where `t=linspace(0,10,400)` and `x=2*sin(pi*t)`, and plot both `x` and `y` on the same axes."

So far, I've gotten this code to work:

```
t=linspace(0,10,400);
x=2*sin(pi*t);
y(x>1) = 1; y(x<-1) = -1;  y(x>-1 & x<1) = 0;
hold on;
plot(x);
plot(y,'r')
legend('x','y')
```

but I believe there's a more concise way to write line 3 of my code so that it doesn't require 3 separate statements, just 1. Hopefully someone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
y = x .* (abs(x) <= 1) + (x > 1) - (x < -1);
```

**Explanation:**

Suppose you have `x = [-2.0 -1.5 -1.0 -0.5 0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0]`

Let's break the expression in three parts and see the result:

```
(1) abs(x) <= 1 --> 0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
(2) x > 1 --------> 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
(3) x < -1 -------> 1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Note that part `(1)` has ones where `x` is between `-1` and `1`, part `(2)` has ones where `x` is greater than `1`, and part `(3)` has ones where `x` is less than `-1`.

What we do first is a dot product between the part `(1)` and `x`, which gives us this:

```
x .* (abs(x) <= 1) -> 0.0 0.0 -1.0 -0.5 0 0.5 1.0 0.0 0.0]
```

Now, we sum part `(2)` to this to fill the vector with ones (in this case, at the end):

```
x .* (abs(x) <= 1) + (x > 1) -> 0.0 0.0 -1.0 -0.5 0 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.0]
```

To finish, we subtract part `(3)`, so it will fill the remaining zeros with -1:

```
x .* (abs(x) <= 1) + (x > 1) - (x < -1) -> -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -0.5 0 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.0]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! This was exactly what I've been trying to find. You even made me realize I was doing the problem wrong on my own.

Do you think you could explain how this works exactly? I'm having a little trouble following it and I'm not positive I could've ever found this.

Comment: Thanks so much! You've been a huge help.

Comment: I've gotta ask though, I'm lost on why parts 2 and 3 replace the values of x with 1 and -1 respectively as opposed to part 1 which is just getting the dot product of the values in x and 1. Why doesn't part 2 have a similar output to part 1 and part 3 output the opposites of the x values?

Comment: Part 2 is a vector containing ones only where x is greater than 1, and zeros elsewhere. If you sum that vector with part 1's vector, you have two situations for each value: if part 2's value is zero, the sum will mantain part 1's value, because anything plus zero equals zero; if part 2's value is a one, the sum will be one too, because part 1 is zero on these cases. The same goes for part 3, except we want to replace zeros with -1 instead of 1.